# Is LIC MF ETF NIFTY 100 deductible under Indian Income tax sec 80C?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, mutual-funds

Is LIC MF ETF NIFTY 100 deductible under Indian Income tax sec 80C?

http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Charts%20%20Tables/Deductions.htm lists:

■  Subscription to any units of any approved mutual fund referred to in section 10(23D), provided amount of subscription to such units is subscribed only in 'eligible issue of capital' referred to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only ELSS are eligible for tax deductions under 80C.

The said fund is not ELSS.